# Need help with conceptual understanding of functions

Tags: functions

A function is defined to be $f(x)=-1+ln(\sqrt{x^2-1})$.

1. What is the largest possible domain of this function? Is it $x>1$ or $x<-1$ or something else?
2. Why does this function, with domain defined as the largest possible domain, not have an inverse function?

If the largest possible domain is either $x>1$ or $x<-1$, why is there no inverse function? It passes the horizontal line test.

3. For domain $x>1$, explain why $f'(x)=0$ and $f^{-1}$$'$$(x)=0$ have no solutions.

I know that for $x>1$, $f^{-1}(x)=\sqrt{e^{2x+2}+1}$ and $f'(x)=\frac{x}{x^2-1}$, but must $D_{f'}$ be a subset of $D_f$?

Comment: A function can't have a derivative where it is not defined !

Comment: @Yves Daoust I defined it?

Comment: Note that on the maximal real domain, $f(x) = f(-x)$, so $f$ is not 1-1. This means the inverse function is not uniquely defined (the sign of the square root is ambiguous). If you restrict the domain of $f$ appropriately, you can define an inverse.

Comment: What do you mean by "I defined it?" ?

Comment: Wonderful question! By the way, with “upright” functions like $\sin$ or $\log$, it's good to use \ before the name, like in `\ln`, so it appears as $\ln$ as opposed to $ln$ ;) for more tricks, check out [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)!

Answer (score 0):

Let $D$ be the largest possible domain. Then $x \in D \iff x^2>1$ Hence

$D=( - \infty,-1) \cup (1, \infty)$.

$f$ is not injective on $D$ since for $x \in D$ we have $f(x)=f(-x)$.

For $x>1$ we have $f'(x)=\frac{x}{x^2-1}>0$.

The rest is your turn !

Answer (score 0):

The largest possible domain (sometimes called the natural domain) is the domain that satisfies the system of inequalities
$$
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
x^2-1\ge0 \\
\sqrt{x^2-1}>0
\end{aligned}
\right.
.
$$
The first comes from the square root and the second comes from the log. Solving that gives $\{x:x<1 \ \text{or} \ x>1\}$.

The function does not have an inverse because it fails the horizontal line test, since $f(-2)=f(2)$, to give an example.

Since $f'$ is defined in terms of $f(x)$, yes the domain of $f'$ must be a subset of the domain of $f$. To explain why the equations have no solutions, simply try to solve them until you get a simpler equation which is easier to see has no solutions on $\{x:x>1\}$.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

$$f(x)=-1+\ln(\sqrt{x^2-1})$$

The domain of $\ln$ is $(0, \infty)$. So we need to have 
\begin{align}
   \sqrt{x^2-1} &> 0 \\
   x^2 - 1 &> 0 \\
   x^2 &> 1 \\
   |x| &> 1 \\
\end{align}

That is, $x \in (-\infty, -1) \cup (1, \infty)$

To be invertible, a function needs to be one-to-one. Since $f(x) = f(-x)$ for all $x$ in the domain of $f$, this function is massively not one-to-one.

If $x > 1$, then $f'(x) = \dfrac{x}{x^2-1}$ is always a positive number. That means that, when $x> 1, \ f(x)$ is a strictly increasing function. Strictly increasing functions don't have maximum values. So, for $x >1, \ f'(x)$ cannot be equal to $0$. The same goes for ${f^{-1}}'(x) = \dfrac{e^{2x+2}}{\sqrt{1 + e^{2x+2}}}$.

Must $D_{f'}$ be a subset of $D_f$? Yes of course it must. I'm not sure that this quastion is what you really meant to ask.